# Speeding up an optimal path function

Tags: matlab

I have a script which finds the optimal path from a node in a transition cost matrix to all other nodes (the DPA function in the folder of functions found here http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39034-finding-optimal-path-on-a-terrain).

The problem I'm having is that this function is exactly what I need, but I need it to run over a 16641 x 16641 matrix (129*129 x 129*129). I'm currently running it over that, but it is taking ages as expected (currently still running at 2 hours!). I will post the entire function at the end but I was wondering if anyone could shed light on whether the following change to the function would make it run considerably faster. I believe the process creating this excessive time to run is

```
for fromNode = 1 : m
        for toNode = 1 : m
            aij = P(toNode, fromNode);
            dj = aij + prevStageCostMat(fromNode);
            if dj < stageCostMat(toNode)
                stageCostMat(toNode) = dj;
                predMat(toNode, stage) = fromNode;
            end         
        end % end toNode
    end % end fromNode
```

where m=16641. Must the function propagate through all nodes regardless to give the right result (I guess the question is, am I understanding correctly what the function is doing?) or is there any way to speed up the calculation do you think?

The main function page says

```
% Keep in mind that DPA propagates through all the nodes. Basically DPA
% tries to find optimal path from one nodes to all nodes
```

Here is the full function, if anyone could give me any insight I'd greatly appreciate it (and if you need any more clarification please let me know as I understand if I've explained this confusingly), thanks!

```
function [stageCostMat, predMat, converged] = dpa(P, startNode, endNode, maxIteration)

% This is the function that will perform the DPA.
%
% Assume we have n number of nodes. P matrix is the transition cost matrix
% with dimension of n x n(square matrix). P(toNode, fromNode) shows
% transition cost from fromNode to toNode.
%
% stageCostMat shows the cost at each node for current iteration.
% stageCostMat(c) = current stage cost matrix at node c.
%
% predMat shows parent/predecessor node of each node for every stage.
% predMat(c, s): parent of node c during stage s.
%
% manurung.auralius@gmail.com
% 17.11.2012
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Is the algortihm converged?
converged = 0;

% Cost matrix is a square matrix, m = n
[m, n] = size(P);

% Assume we will probably converge after n stages
stageCostMat = ones(1, m) * inf;

% Initial cost, no initial cost
stageCostMat(startNode) = 0;

% Predecessor matrix to trace back the optimum path, we will record parent of
% each node on each iteration
predMat = zeros(m, maxIteration); 

% Stage-by-stage, we move from start node to terminal node
for stage = 2 : maxIteration    

    % Find connection from any nodes to any nodes, keep the smaller cost
    prevStageCostMat = stageCostMat;
    stageCostMat = ones(1, m) * inf;

    for fromNode = 1 : m
        for toNode = 1 : m
            aij = P(toNode, fromNode);
            dj = aij + prevStageCostMat(fromNode);
            if dj < stageCostMat(toNode)
                stageCostMat(toNode) = dj;
                predMat(toNode, stage) = fromNode;
            end         
        end % end toNode
    end % end fromNode

    % Termination
%     if (stageCostMat == prevStageCostMat)
%         converged = 1;
%         break;
%     end

    if (predMat(endNode, stage) == endNode) || (predMat(endNode, stage-1) > 0) && (predMat(endNode, stage) == predMat(endNode, stage-1))
        converged = 1;
        break;
    end

end

predMat = predMat(:, 1:stage);
```

Comment: there are probably a few things to speed this up, but this is majorly dependent on your matrix. The loop checks every possible connection (from 1:m to 1:m) and this could probably be reduced. how sparse is the matrix P?

Comment: Okay, in P every value is `Inf` except for the cells on the diagonal and the cells immediately one above and one below the diagonal

Comment: terrific! in that case you would only have to loop from thorugh (m-1):(m+1) in the inner for loop and you would reduce the calculation to way less than 1% as all the `Inf` calculation wont generate anything anyway. Can you adapt that on yourself? otherwise we can help, but we would need example data for: `(P, startNode, endNode, maxIteration)`

Comment: So literally just  `for fromNode = 1 : m`
        `for toNode = (m-1) : (m+1)`
            `aij = P(toNode, fromNode);`
            `dj = aij + prevStageCostMat(fromNode);`
            `if dj < stageCostMat(toNode)`
                `stageCostMat(toNode) = dj;`
                `predMat(toNode, stage) = fromNode;`
            `end`         
        `end % end toNode`
    `end % end fromNode`
or something a little more advanced?

Answer (score 0):

a little more advanced. `toNode` relates to the current position of `forNode` and you have to dodge the cases where `toNode` would exceed the matrix dimensions:

```
for fromNode = 1 : m 
    %relativ to fromNode bc its always on the diagonal
    for toNode = (fromNode-1) : (fromNode+1) 
        %for the first and alse fromNode toNode would be out of the array limits
        if toNode==0 | toNode==m+1
            continue 
        end
        aij = P(toNode, fromNode); 
        dj = aij + prevStageCostMat(fromNode); 
        if dj < stageCostMat(toNode) 
            stageCostMat(toNode) = dj; 
            predMat(toNode, stage) = fromNode; 
        end
    end % end toNode 
end % end fromNode
```

i would recommend you to try this on on data where you have the solution from the old loop to check if the soulution is still the same. the time should be majorly reduced, as you only calculate 3 out of 16641 loops.

Comment: This script runs fine but then causes an error when the next script required for the overall task is run (I'm not sure if you wanted to open a private conversation to discuss this?)

Comment: Sure. But i wont be here today anymore, so how about tomorrow?

Comment: That works fine with me, although I'm not too sure how to initiate a private chat!

Comment: not sure either, but if you figure it out please post the group here

Comment: I generally find that once the comments exceeds a certain limit the option to private chat is suggested

Comment: Sorry, I was away at the weekend so could not tend to this Matlab problem but are you free today to readdress the problem?

Comment: I am! and i created this [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123150/speeding-up-an-optimal-path-function)